How to use transformed column names in Custom Transformer
Let's say I have a sklearn Pipeline, with preprocessing step and modeling step.
I have a few Column Transformers in preprocessing which change the dataframe column names due to applying one hot encoding.
Now before applying a model (Decision Tree) I want to update the variable monotonic constraints that is passed to the Decision Tree.
How do I create a Custom Transfer or FunctionTransformer which checks the updated column names after applying transformations and passes the (or updates the variable) monotonic constraints to next step.
I know how to do these things individually, just struggling to keep it inside the sklearn Pipeline and generalize it.

I don't know of a straightforward way to do this. Metadata routing works for fitting and scoring, but not __init__ parameters like the monotonicity constraints. // You may be able to get things working by carefully arranging the ColumnTransformers; if you are open to that kind of solution, provide a representative example of your preprocessing steps.
